# Zend2 Destroying SessionCookie

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i am setting cookie in my app, 
i want to destroy the old cookie when it find the secure HTTPS chanel.
this is the code that i used to destroy the session Cookie

```
            if($cookie['secure'] == 1 && isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')
            {
                \Zend_Session::destroy( true );

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('main_login');

            }
```

but it show me blank page, and session is not destroying.

Comment: are you sure this is zf2?

Comment: \Zend_Session::destroy( true );
this syntax used in zend framework 1, i need to destroy session cookies in zend2, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have a container:

```
$session = new Container('bar');
```

You've got 3 different ways to unset:

```
unset($session['bar']);

unset($session->bar);

$session->offsetUnset('bar');
```

Or clear:

```
$session->getManager()->getStorage()->clear('bar');
```

Comment: but i dont know the namespace of the sessionCookie